# Problem with beamer and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

For some reason this code doesn't work and I don't know why:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{extarrow}
\usepackage{fontenc,mathtext}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},every join/.style={->}}
```

[...]

```
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usecolortheme{progressbar}
\usefonttheme{progressbar}
\useinnertheme{progressbar}
\useoutertheme{progressbar}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees,arrows}
```

[...]

```
\begin{document}
\frame{
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90]
\matrix(a)[matrix of math nodes,
row sep=2.5em, column sep=2.5em,
text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.20ex]
{\bigwedge^2 S^m&S^m&S&0\\
F_2&F_1&S&0\\};
\path[->](a-1-1) edge (a-1-2);
\path[->](a-1-2) edge (a-1-3);
\path[->](a-1-3) edge (a-1-4);
\path[->](a-2-1) edge (a-2-2);
\path[->](a-2-2) edge (a-2-3);
\path[->](a-2-3) edge (a-2-4);
\path[->](a-1-1) edge node[auto] {$\gamma$}(a-2-1);
\path[->](a-1-2) edge node[auto] {$\cong$}(a-2-2);
\path[->](a-1-3) edge node[auto] {$id$}(a-2-3);
\path[->](a-2-3) edge (a-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
}
```

Any idea of why doesn't it work?

Comment: What error do you get or what is not how it should be?

Comment: Please always give a [**minimal** working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that shows the error, i.e. remove any unrelated material also from the preamble (see the link for more info). In this case you only need `\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document} ...
` to recreate the error. Half the time you find the issue yourself during this process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have not tried specifically on your example, so I cannot be sure if it works or not.
However I remember having a similar problem when using tikz and matrix. What I did was adding an option to the matrix :

```
ampersand replacement=\&
```

and then replace every piece of my code as such:

```
  \matrix[row sep=0.01cm,column sep=0.5cm,ampersand replacement=\&] {
    \&
    \node (A) [tree] {$\mathbf{A}$}; \&
    \&
    \\
    \node (v0) [state] {$v_{src};v'_{src})$}; \&
    \&
    \node (vn)   [state] {$(v_{snk};v'_{snk})$};     \&
    \\
    \&
    \node (B)   [tree] {$\mathbf{B}$};       \&
    \&
    \\
  }
```

I hope this helped. Sorry I did not have much time to really check your issue specifically.

Comment: +1 This should help because it avoids the issue with the catcode change of `&` (by avoiding the use of `&`).

Answer (score 4):

The `\matrix` command of TikZ changes the catcode of `&` and is therefore not allowed in an argument of another macro like `\frame` or an pseudo-environment like `{frame}`. This can be fixed by using `\begin{frame}[fragile] .. \end{frame}` instead. It makes sure that all catcode changes (for verbatim mode etc.) work correctly.

Works:

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90]
\matrix(a)[matrix of math nodes,
row sep=2.5em, column sep=2.5em,
text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.20ex]
{\bigwedge^2 S^m&S^m&S&0\\
F_2&F_1&S&0\\};
\path[->](a-1-1) edge (a-1-2);
\path[->](a-1-2) edge (a-1-3);
\path[->](a-1-3) edge (a-1-4);
\path[->](a-2-1) edge (a-2-2);
\path[->](a-2-2) edge (a-2-3);
\path[->](a-2-3) edge (a-2-4);
\path[->](a-1-1) edge node[auto] {$\gamma$}(a-2-1);
\path[->](a-1-2) edge node[auto] {$\cong$}(a-2-2);
\path[->](a-1-3) edge node[auto] {$id$}(a-2-3);
\path[->](a-2-3) edge (a-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{frame}
```